# How to Check Teradata Table Definitions

Tags: sql

In my Teradata SQL Assistant Client, I can right-click a table and select **Show Definition**, this will display the column types and how they are defined.

Is there a query that can be run to give me the same output? More specifically I'm trying to display the definition of a view that is created from certain tables that I do not have SELECT or VIEW DEFINITION access to.

Answer (score 19):

```
SHOW TABLE {Database_Name}.{Table_Name};

SHOW VIEW {Database_Name}.{View_Name};
```

Comment: There is a gotcha to this command - if the table definition is too long it is split across several rows. You have to concatenate them first to get the final result. Very weird, I know..